# rails form_for with associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

In the official rails guide, I came across

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
....
<%end %>
```

I am not quite sure what the two parameters of form_for are representing. I think the first parameter **@article** is referring to the associated model of comments and article, and the second parameter appears to be creating a new comment.

Why are they there and why are both parameters in an array..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is being demonstrated by this particular code snippet is **nested routing**.

## Non-nested Routing

In a `form_for` call, the method argument is used to determine which resource URL the form should submit to. For example, if we have `form_for(@article)` then the form will submit to the routes for the "article" resource (either `POST /articles` or `PUT/PATCH /articles/:id` depending on if the record was new or existing).

## Nested Routing

A nested route is one that has two levels of resources in the URL. For example, you might have a "comment" resource which is *nested under* an "article" resource (because comments belong to articles). In this case, the routes for a `form_for` would look like `POST articles/:article_id/comments` and `PUT articles/:article_id/comments/:id`.

### Array as an argument

The array as an argument to the `form_for` call indicates that the resources will be nested, and therefore to submit the form to a nested route.

For deeply nested routes (not recommended) you could continue to add objects to the array for every level that you need, e.g. `[@category, @article, @comment]` which goes to `/categories/:category_id/articles/:article_id/comments`

---

In the particular case shown by the OP, it will submit to the `POST "articles/#{@article.id}/comments"` because `@articles.comments.build` is a new comment.